# UINavigationBar with ProgressView

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to implement the progress view as shown in the image below.

Does anyone know how to implement such a progress view in UINavigationBar?

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried, what did it do wrong?

Comment: @H2CO3 Check my edited link, if you are unable to open the link.

Comment: @Wain I want to try something like subclassing the UINavigationBar, but don't know the exact way, how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather simple. You just need to add a progress view as a subview to the navigation bar.

But you're also right in wanting to create a subclass of a UINavigationBar. You can set the custom navigation bar in code with:

```
- (instancetype)initWithNavigationBarClass:(Class)navigationBarClass toolbarClass:(Class)toolbarClass
```

Or if you're using Storyboard, you can select your subclass in the Navigation Controller Scene in the Document Outline. (the left sidebar)

In your UINavigationBar subclass you'll want to create a method that is accessible from any of the view controllers in your navigation controller hierarchy, so that you can set the progress value from anywhere. Something like this:

```
-(void)updateProgress:(CGFloat)progress animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

That way, in one of the view controllers that needs to update this progress, you can call the above method by grabbing a reference to your custom bar class:

```
MYNavigationBar *bar = (MYNavigationBar *)[[self navigationController] navigationBar];
[bar updateProgress:0.5 animated:NO];
```

Lastly, you'll want to also add some methods to your UINavigationBar subclass to hide and show the bar, probably with some animation.

Answer (score 0):

This must be useful. Try using it as a example to write your code.

https://github.com/ninjinkun/NJKWebViewProgress

Comment: Sorry Rafael, but that is not what i actually wanted. I want to create the exactly same as it is shown in the image link.